# I can't create a file download controller

Tags: javascript, file, controller, stream, sails.js

When I try to use the .pipe() function in my controller I get an error and I don't know why. Attached my code below, thank you very much for the help in advance

```
 const fs =require('fs');

module.exports={
inputs:{
    name_file:{
        type:"string",
        required:true
    }
},
exits: {
    success: {
      description: "Return matching data.",
    },

    defaultError: {
      description: "It catches any error.",
      responseType: "defaultError",
    },
  },

fn:function (inputs,exits){
    //Comprobamos si el fichero viene en la peticion
    if (!inputs.name_file) return exits.defaultError("No se ha adjuntado el nombre del archivo")
    var nameFile=inputs.name_file

    //Creamos ruta completa del fichero
    var URL_FILE=process.cwd()
    URL_FILE= URL_FILE.concat("\\.tmp\\uploads\\",nameFile,'.csv')

    //Comprobamos si el fichero existe
    fs.access(URL_FILE,fs.constants.F_OK,(err)=>{
        return "El fichero no existe"
    })
    var response={}
    var SkipperDisk = require('skipper-disk');
    var fileAdapter = SkipperDisk(/* optional opts */);

    // Stream the file down
    var filedown=fileAdapter.read(URL_FILE)
    filedown.on('error', function (err){
      return exits.defaultError(err);
   })
   filedown.on('line',(linea)=>{
    console.log(linea)
   })
    filedown.pipe(exits.success(response))
}
```

}

**TypeError: Cannot read property 'on' of undefined```**